# Redis Streams fetch multiple values with XREAD

Tags: python, c, redis, blocking, redis-streams

I have a redis stream "mystream" and I am trying to use:

**XREAD COUNT 5 BLOCK 50000 STREAMS mystream $**

to read five new entries appended to mystream with blocking for 50s. As soon as I execute command to add data to mystream using:

**XADD mystream a 5 b 6**

the blocked command exits with giving single entry as the output.

Is there any way of XREAD command using which I can receive multiple entries appended from now on till 50s or do I have to call XREAD multiple times for achieving the same ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is something that is not meant for usage of `XREAD BLOCK`. I would suggest the [XREVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/xrevrange) command:

```
xrevrange mystream + - COUNT 5
```

min: "+" - indicates the highest id of the stream and
max: "-" - indicates the lowest id of the stream.
Instead of "-" you could also pass a TIMESTAMP which would limit your `XREVRANGE` results to a desired time to `TIMESTAMP` seconds ago (inclusive).

```
xrevrange mystream + 1596617691455 COUNT 5
```

The suggestion above is not achieving the same `blocking` behavior. If you would still like to *react* to incoming data you might look into [Redis Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub). Subscribe to a topic, and write your own logic to handle incoming data. There is a [webchat example](https://gist.github.com/pietern/348262).

You could also use `XREAD BLOCK` to detect the min value of your `XREVRANGE` command:

```
XREAD COUNT 5 BLOCK 50000 STREAMS mystream $
XREVRANGE mystream + [returned_xread_key] COUNT 5
```

I am sorry, but I cannot provide examples in the C language, here's in Python:

```
import redis
import time
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis("0.0.0.0", decode_responses=True)
response = redis_client.xread({'mystream': "$"}, count=1, block=50000)
if len(response) > 0:
    min_value = response[0][1][0][0] # [['mystream', [('1596618943439-0', {'mykey': 'myval'})]]]
    time.sleep(50) # wait for the end of the window
    entries = redis_client.xrevrange('mystream', max="+", min=min_value, count=5)
```